# Eclipse plugin development- Different folder with different popup menu options in package explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, popupmenu

How can I create different popup menus options when I right-click in *Package Explorer*.

Like for example I have some folder with different name in *Package Explorer*.
Now what I want when I right-click on a folder it show me some popup menus and when right-click on another folder it shows some different popup menus.

That is **different folder with different popup menu options** .
And some way how can I differ those folders with each other to set different popup menu options.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do 2 steps :

First : remove existing items in popup menu, this can be done in 2 ways :
through activities, or equinox transformations

Activities : you use id in plugin.xml to filter content you don't want to display

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
   <category id="z.ex.commands.category"
         name="ReadMe Cat"/>
   <activity id="z.ex.commands.activity"
         name="ReadMe Act"/>
   <activityPatternBinding activityId="z.ex.commands.activity"
         isEqualityPattern="true"
         pattern="org.eclipse.ui.examples.readmetool/org.eclipse.ui.examples.readmetool.wizards.new.file"/>
   <categoryActivityBinding activityId="z.ex.commands.activity"
         categoryId="z.ex.commands.category">
</extension>
```

The Plug-in Registry view can be used to find the IDs for actions

I never try with equinox transformation but here is the link :
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Transforms

Second : add items to the popup- menu :

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
         <command
               commandId="my id"
               label="my command label"
               style="push">
          <visibleWhen>
           <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
            <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false">
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
               <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.java"     />
             </adapt>
            </iterate>
           </with>
         </visibleWhen>
       </command>
      </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

You have to change the IResource to the desire target (IFolder in your case I believe, and apply the filter desired to your file name instead of *.java

Comment: It dint worked for me. What i understood is that  whenever user right click on any .java file it shows a popup menu with label "my command label" is it??

Comment: You have to run a new eclipse instance, running eclipse + the plugin containing menu extension describe above